# PIL TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), |u1

Tags: arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I have a `numpy.ndarray` of shape `(1,28,28)` and values are floating point in range [0,1]. My ultimate goal is to save the array as a png image.

Even after transposing the array and multiplying it with 255 so as to get uint values, still, it throws the error `*** TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), |u1`.

I am using the following code:

```
im = Image.fromarray((img.transpose(1,2,0) * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I already worked on the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51979554/typeerror-cannot-handle-the-data-type-in-pil-image).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your image is greyscale, you need to pass PIL a 2-D array, i.e. the shape must be `h,w` not `h,w,1`.

```
im = Image.fromarray((img[0] * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```